# Как подставить значение из кастомного поля Рубрики на страницу?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Через ACF (advanced custom fields) создал кастомное поле типа Изображение. Добавил изображение внутри рубрики. На страницу рубрики вывожу так:

```
<?php
        $categories = get_categories( [
        'parent' => 7,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'hide_empty' => 0
      ] );

      if( $categories ){
        foreach( $categories as $cat ){
          $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
          $category_name = $cat->name;
        ?>
          <div class="txt_col dflex fdcol sqare_img_txt">
            <div class="txt_col_h_wrapper">
              <h3 class="txt_col_header">
                <?php echo $category_name ?>
              </h3>
              <div class="txt_col_img">
                <img src="<?php the_field('post-image'); ?>">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="txt_col_btn">
              <a class="o_btn" href="<?php echo $category_link ?>">Подробнее</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php
        }
      }
      ?>
```

Изображение из кастомного поля не выводит. Как вывести Изображение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php the_field('post-image','category_' . $cat->cat_ID);?>" alt="">
```

Сталкивался на неделе с такой проблемой, помогло.
У ACF в документации есть такое, что нужно передавать помимо ключа поля значения 'category_' и ID категории. Как я понял, $cat->cat_ID именно отвечает за ID категории

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не смог разобраться в доках.